# How to find the solution for this integral equation?

Tags: polynomials, improper-integrals, roots, gamma-function, integral-equations

I'm trying to solve this integral equation:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{zi}+t^{-zi}}{e^t}dt=0$$
For the *least* value of $z$. This is, if $S=\{z_0,...,z_n\}$ is a set of solutions, and $|\lambda|=\mathrm{inf}\{|z_0|,...,|z_n|\}$, then $\lambda\in S$ is the desired solution.

After extensive transformations, I managed to reduce the integral on the LHS to an infinite polynomial $p$:
$$p(z)=1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z_+}}\frac{\mathcal{D}(n)}{2\cdot n!}\left(\Pi_n(z)+\Pi_n(-z)\right)$$

Where
$$\Pi_n(z)=\prod_{s=0}^n(zi-s)$$ $n$ runs through all positive intergers, and $\mathcal{D}(n)$ is the *number of derangements*, hence:
$$\mathcal{D}(n)=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
So the problem reduces to finding the absolute infimum of a set of roots of an infinite complicated polynomial $p$... But how can this be done? Any help, alternative solution, or insight on the problem will be appreciated.

---

**Edit**

I should've probably clarified this in the first edit:
I've found two solution approximations by brute force that satisfy the lower bound constraints:
$$z_0=\lambda$$
$$z_1=-\lambda$$
Where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ shows $3.4397<|\lambda|<3.4398$. This solves the equation to an extent, however, I need the error on $\lambda$ to be as small as possible, so I need a good approximant for it (this is the reason why the polynomial equivalent of the equation was introduced). I've never solved for the root of an infinite-degree polynomial before, so i'm not quite sure if this is even possible, but it is the only way to get an approximant that i could think about.

Comment: You can write the integrand as $2  e^{-t}\cos(z\log t)$ if that helps anything.

Comment: There seems to be a zero near $z=3.27$.

Comment: You want to solve $(-i z)!+(i z)!=0$ which requires inverting the factorial function

Comment: @ТymaGaidash i got the function from considering the real part of the gamma function. Idk about the inverse of the gamma function, however. Do you think there is a nice approximant for the solution?

Comment: I'm seeing $z_0 = 3.4397353$. I rewrote the integrand as noted above and made the substitution $u := \log t$. The resultant integral over $-\infty < u < \infty$ was split into integrals over $-\infty < u< 0$ and $0 < u < \infty$, each being integrated using `integrate.quad` from `scipy` (Python) using `weight='cos'`. Simple bisection reports this zero, which I believe to be accurate to all shown digits. I'm interesting to learn what you end up finding.

Comment: @Aruralreader thanks! I'll keep the post updated with the details.

Comment: With Tyma's suggestion and a _bit_ of help from Sage, $z_0 = 3.43973531064036288932295331515836154693470267134546969650458351029501374220$ to 75 significant digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{zi}+t^{-zi}}{e^t}\,dt=\Gamma(1+iz)+\Gamma(1-iz)$$

So, considering that we need to find the first zero  of function
$$f(z)=\Gamma(1+iz)+\Gamma(1-iz)$$ consider as a very first estimate
$$z_0=\pi$$ and use the $\color{red}{\text{first}}$ iterate of a Newton-like method of order $n$; this gives an explicit closed form expression for each *approximate*.

Converted to decimals, the results are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_1^{(n)}   & \text{method}\\
 2 &  3.3637901 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 &  3.4227503 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 &  3.4365242 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  3.4392040 & \text{no name}\\
 6 &  3.4396546 & \text{no name}\\
 7 &  3.4397239 & \text{no name}\\
 8 &  3.4397338 & \text{no name}\\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty &3.4397353 & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$